# javascript to convert an array of local dates and times to UTC in milliseconds since 1-1-1970?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

given an array of dates and times in Eastern Standard Time like...

```
var dates = [
new Date(2015, 6, 15, 14, 00, 00),
new Date(2015, 6, 15, 18, 30, 30),
new Date(2015, 7, 30, 0, 15, 52),
new Date(2015, 9, 8, 10, 08, 38)];
```

How would you convert these upcoming dates to UTC in milliseconds since 1-1-1970 and save those values in a new array?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date.getTime()` function of Javascript

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: What about the time zone?

Comment: `Date()` constructor if called with more than 1 args will use local timezone

Comment: I think the OP mentioned the times are in EST and he wants the result in UTC.

Comment: From the reference: The value returned by the getTime() method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: His question specifically said that his Date objects are already in EST, and the getTime() func return milliseconds in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Iterrate the array, use `date.getTime()` to get the seconds from 1-1-1970 and than push it into an new array.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h22f5rw8/

**Edit**

The code if JSFiddle going down or isn't reachable:

```
var dates = [
    new Date(2015, 6, 15, 14, 00, 00),
    new Date(2015, 6, 15, 18, 30, 30),
    new Date(2015, 7, 30, 0, 15, 52),
    new Date(2015, 9, 8, 10, 08, 38)
];

var dates_ms = [];

dates.forEach( function(datum) {
    dates_ms.push(datum.getTime());
});

console.log( dates_ms );
```

output: `[1436961600000, 1436977830000, 1440886552000, 1444291718000]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the subtraction operator.

```
var oldDate = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
var newDates = []
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    newDates.push(dates[i] - oldDate);
}
```

EDIT: Just realized you wanted to modify the original array
EDIT: Misread the question

Comment: @A1rPun You're right. This was written before I had coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var timestamps = dates.map(function(d){return +d});
```